# Run Feature file with different login

Tags: cucumber-jvm, gherkin, cucumberjs

Here we need to run the same feature file with different login and provide login user name from tags.

Run the feature file with user1 and user2

```
@user1 @user2

Feature: Feature-1

Background : 
 Given I am login with user

Scenario: 

Scenario:
```

Run the feature file with user1

```
@user1 

Feature: Feature-2

Background : 
 Given I am login with user

Scenario: 

Scenario:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Scenario Outline concept of gherkin language where you can pass user name and password as a Example. For ex:

```
-- Feature file

Scenario Outline: Verify Login Functionality
  Given There is a user "<username>" and <password>"
   When I login to the application
Examples:
|username|password|
|user1|pass1|
|user2|pass2|

-- Spec file

Given(/^There is a user (.*) and (.*)$/, async function(username, password) {
    driver.findElement(Locator to identify the username element).sendKeys(username);
    driver.findElement(Locator to identify the password element).sendKeys(password);
});
```

Here, same test scenario written above will be repeated for two different users.
Take these two regular expressions as a parameter in spec file and send it to username and password text fields using selenium

Comment: Once I log in I would perform some action, then log out and Then I want relogin with another user, to perform the same operation.

Comment: Scenario Outline will work in such a way, same test scenario will be repeated with the number of examples you provided. For example, first it will login with user1 , do some operation and logout. After successful logout, cucumber will not move to the another scenario. It will repeat same scenario with user2 and will perform same operation what you did with user1.